# Scalable circles with dynamic numbers inside

Tags: html, css, user-interface, scalable

Apologies if this has been asked and answered already, as I was not able to find an appropriate solution to this problem.

I need to work on a site navigation that require some numbers to be placed inside circles. The circles will increase in diameter based on the length of the text inside. I'm looking for a very elegant, preferably css only solution for this. Please note the alignment of the circles here with respect to the entire row and label text on the mock up attached.
[image: Here is the mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It required some CSS trickery to get this working, but this works in the latest version Chrome and Firefox. Let me know if you have any other questions.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #9653DA;
  font: 600 14px sans-serif;
}
.nav-table {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.nav-col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.text {
  margin: 1em;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.icon div {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  top: -7px; /* Half of font-size, in our case it is (14px / 2) */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-table">

  <div class="nav-row">
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="icon">
        <div>20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="icon">
        <div>300</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="icon">
        <div>50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="icon">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav-row">
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="text">Japanese</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="text">Main Course</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="text">Non Vegetarian</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-col">
      <div class="text">Beginners</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant. I was just about to start with a js solution and got your answer. Will try implementing this and let you know. Only question, is it possible to get the number and label together inside one parent? I would like this to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: @AnandANair that's great to hear! JavaScript would've made it easier indeed. I'm glad it at least partially answered your question, could you mark it as answered?